# How shall we set up to run a command automatically once no user activity for a specified amount of time?

Tags: power-management

Is there some way to set up to run a command (e.g. `pm-suspend` or any other command) automatically, whenever there is no user activity (mainly no user input from keyboard, touchpad, mouse, maybe except  user-started long running programs) for a specified amount of time?

For example, is there a system directory where I can put a configuration script which will be called automatically once user is inactive in the above sense for a specified amount of time?

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04, and I prefer solutions which are not binded to specific desktop environments.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use crontab/cron. But this is just for automation.

Comment: Does crontab/cron detect no user activity for a certain amount of time?

Comment: Sadly no, thats why i mentioned that it is just for automation.

Comment: one google search https://askubuntu.com/a/202145/93232

Comment: @Kiwy Does xprintidle allow me to set up running a command or script once no user activity for a specified amount of time?

Comment: no it allow you to calculte time people has been inactive so either with crontab or deamon script you could check people connected and inactive and take action accordingly

Comment: Maybe you can use @Kiwy suggestion and combine it with the watchdog daemon https://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog So, if any user has been idle less than x minutes, touch the watchdog, otherwise don't touch it and the system will reboot ( I think you can configure this to perform other action instead).